# ошибка в xcode с computed переменной

Tags: xcode, swift

Доброго всем!

Изучаю лекции из стенфордского университета на сайте bestkora.com

перевод с анг.на русский
в лекции xcode 7, а у меня xcode 6.2 (OS X 10.9) проблема возникла с переменной

я объявил UILabel как оутлет и назвал его display

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var displayValue: Double {

    get {
        return Double(display.text!)!
    }

    set {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
    }
}
```

все как указанно в лекции, но выдает ошибку

```
Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

что не так, не понять

Лекция тут https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jZOSo2e4NmOXFjc29BSXlHWlk/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Замените

```
return Double(display.text!)!
```

на

```
return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
```

Вариант 2. Обновите macOS и Xcode

Comment: для обновления нужен ssd пока возможности нет купить ssd. а на hdd не работоспобный комп с MacOS